# Black highlighted box stuck on my screen

Tags: 20.04

This bug occurs to me quite frequently lately, where a word (highlighted in black) gets stuck somewhere on my screen and it never goes away no matter how much refreshes I do, it only goes way with a restart (which requires me to save everything first, reopens them, etc.)

Notice the word "Collapse all" below.
[image: Notice the word "Collapse all" below]

It can also show other different words in different positions.

Does anyone have a permanent fix for this?